# how can i use loop in c# database selection

Tags: c#, database

my code is like this:

```
    dt1 = dt1
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("Transaction_x0020_Type"))
                        &&(r.Field<string>("Transaction_x0020_Type").ToLower().Contains(YrStrList[0].ToLower())
                        ||r.Field<string>("Transaction_x0020_Type").ToLower().Contains(YrStrList[1].ToLower())
                        ||r.Field<string>("Transaction_x0020_Type").ToLower().Contains(YrStrList[2].ToLower())
                        ||r.Field<string>("Transaction_x0020_Type").ToLower().Contains(YrStrList[3].ToLower())))
            .AsDataView()
            .ToTable();
```

and I hope can put the following part in a loop:

```
     &&(r.Field<string>("Transaction_x0020_Type").ToLower().Contains(YrStrList[0].ToLower())
                        ||r.Field<string>("Transaction_x0020_Type").ToLower().Contains(YrStrList[1].ToLower())
                        ||r.Field<string>("Transaction_x0020_Type").ToLower().Contains(YrStrList[2].ToLower())
                        ||r.Field<string>("Transaction_x0020_Type").ToLower().Contains(YrStrList[3].ToLower())))
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by putting that code into a loop?

Comment: Why loop when linq is already looping for you?

Comment: "Thanks" at the bottom of the post is not necessary and is frowned upon by the community. Adding it as an edit (and the only change in the edit!) is definitely not needed/appropriate. I have rolled the change back for you.

Comment: A bit of an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish would make a good edit though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're checking *all* values in `YrStrList` and not just the first 4 (of possibly more than 4):

```
&&(YrStrList.Any(y => r.Field<string>("Transaction_x0020_Type")
                       .ToLower()
                       .Contains(y.ToLower())))
```